# How can I convert a vector to a cell array?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a column vector I want to convert to a cell array such as:

```
A = rand(10,1);

B = cell(10,1);
for i=1:10
    B{i} = A(i);
end

B = 
    [0.6221]
    [0.3510]
    [0.5132]
    [0.4018]
    [0.0760]
    [0.2399]
    [0.1233]
    [0.1839]
    [0.2400]
    [0.4173]
```

How can I do this without an explicit for loop?
I tried:

```
B{:} = A(:)
```

and

```
[B{:}] = deal(A)
```

with no luck...

Also if possible, how can I do the same thing for a matrix, i.e. have each element in a cell by itself?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the function [num2cell](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/num2cell.html):

```
B = num2cell(A);
```

Works with matrices too.

Comment: I cant believe I forgot this one! Thanks