# assigning values to a few cells from a vector

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array and a vector, and I want to assign each coordinate of the vector to a different cell, in the same location. 
For example, the j coordinate in a vector becomes the (k,l) coordinate in the (j,1) cell. In pseudo matlab it would look like this:

myCell{:,1}(k,l)=myVector;

Is there a good way to do that without just looping? (performance is an issue.)

a small example:

```
    myCell=cell(2,4);
    myV=[1;2];
    %what I wish to change:
    for j=1:size(myV,1)
        myCell{j,1}(1,1)=myV(j)
    end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll help yourself if you post a small example of your inputs and required outputs.  I don't think I'm the only SOer who is happy to cut and paste and fiddle around but far too lazy to think up some test data for your problem.

Comment: similar question: [How can I convert a vector to a cell array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2083141/97160)

Comment: my problem was with the assignment, but thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the data type in your myVector you'll end up using one of the two following commands.

mat2cell or num2cell

The help pages in Matlab give great detail on the different ways to call the functions, just in case you want to do some fancy grouping of the data and such.

mat2cell: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mat2cell.html

num2cell: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/num2cell.html

Sample Code:

```
myCell=cell(2,4);
myV=[1;2];
% %what I wish to change:
% for j=1:size(myV,1)
%     myCell{j,1}(1,1)=myV(j)
% end
myCell(:,1) = num2cell(myV);
```

Comment: I tried this, but I couldn't assign the cells I created in to myCell{:,1}. should I call for the cell to which I want to a sign in a different way?

Comment: myCell(:,1) = num2cell(myV) worked just fine for me. Try using the regular smooth braces instead of the curly braces.  That of course just replaces the loop you have in your sample code.

Comment: @BenA. This is not the best way. I do not know what the best way is exactly, but I can say that cellfun outmatch this easily